# Spring Batch custom partitioner for input file

Tags: partitioning, flat-file, spring-batch

I'm trying to partition a flat input file containing `;` separated items.
the first item on a line indicates a category and I would like to partition on this category so that for each category a partition is created that will be handled by a dedicated thread.
But I'm puzzled to how I can implement this partitioning logic in a custom `Partitioner`.
The partitioning seems to happen before the chunk oriented step, thus before reading, writing, so it looks like I need to read the file in the custom partitioner line by line, get the category field from the line and collect lines with equal categories and create an `ExecutionContext` for each of these collections?

Am I looking in the right direction?
Can someone with experience provide a small example using a file (may be pseudo code)?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and a desired output example?

Answer (score 0):

I've just hit this question myself. I think that custom Partitioner needs to be paired with a custom ItemReader. ItemReader gets initialized with data from slave step (put there by the Partitioner) and consequently only reads the items that are right for that step.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some custom partitioner implementations in these links [here](https://github.com/sshcherbakov/spring-batch-talk/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/FlatFilePartitioner.java) and [here](https://github.com/mminella/Spring-Batch-Talk-2.0/blob/master/src/main/java/com/michaelminella/springbatch/partition/ColumnRangePartitioner.java) to get an overall idea. But I think you can't flee from the ExecutionContext creation for each partition.